# How do I edit a html file from a different html file? Only JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web, e-commerce

On the product-info.html file, I want it to open the cart.html file on a different window and edit the values on the cart.html file about the name and price on the table that you get from the product-info.html file. However, I don't know how to edit a different file using another one's information. The JS file links both of them but I don't know what to do with that.

PRODUCT-INFO.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/ktane-utils.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="cartCode.js" async></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">"Home"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">"Store"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cart.html">"Cart"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="account.html">"Account"</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>  
            
    <div class="section">
        <div class="page page-bg-01">
            <div class="page-header">
            </div>
            <div class="page-content">
                
                
                <h1><div class="item-title">IPHONE 14 PRO MAX</div></h1>
                <img style='width: 50%' src="img/pictures/products/Iphone14/iphone14.png"><br>
                <img style='width: 10%' src="img/pictures/products/Iphone14/iphone14front.png"><br>
                <p><strong>Store/Iphones</strong></p>
                <div class="item-price">Price: £899.99</div><br>
                <p>Details: Get your gleaming photos taken with a 48MP main camera with an advanced quad-pixel sensor, plus better resolution
                and an extra 256GB storage! The best phone creation in the world is at your hands. Buy only for £899.99!</p><br>
                <button class="btn">Add To Cart</button><br>
                
                
                <h3>OTHER PRODUCTS</h3>
                <div class="advertise">
                    <a href="product details.html"><img style='width: 20%' src="img/pictures/products/Iphone14/iphone14.png">
                    <h4>Iphone 14 Pro Max</h4>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <p>£899.99</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="footer">
                <center><p>Email: <u>t.margub2112@gmail.com</u></p></center>
                <center><p>Facebook: <u>Tawhidul Islam@tawhidulislam.islam.524</u></p></center>
                <center><img style='width: 10%' src="img/pictures/Extra/icon.png" /></center>
                <p style="text-align:left;">Copyright 2022 - Tawhid Productions</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CART.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/ktane-utils.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="cartCode.js" async></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">"Home"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">"Store"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cart.html">"Cart"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="account.html">"Account"</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>  
            
    <div class="section">
        <div class="page page-bg-01">
            <div class="page-header">
            </div>
            <div class="page-content">
            
            <table style='width: 100%'>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody class="cart-items">
            <tr class="cart-row">
                <td><span class="cart-name">Iphone 14 Max Pro, £899.99 </span><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Remove</button></td>
                <td><input class="cart-amt" type="number" value="1"></td>
                <td><span class="cart-price">£899.99</span></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </div>
            </table><br>
            
            <table style='width: 50%'>
            <tbody class="cart-total-container-1">
            <tr class="cart-total-container-2">
                <td>Total</td>
                <td class="cart-total">£899.99</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            
            <div class="footer">
                <center><p>Email: <u>t.margub2112@gmail.com</u></p></center>
                <center><p>Facebook: <u>Tawhidul Islam@tawhidulislam.islam.524</u></p></center>
                <center><img style='width: 10%' src="img/pictures/Extra/icon.png" /></center>
                <p style="text-align:left;">Copyright 2022 - Tawhid Productions</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CARTCODE.JS

```
if(document.readyState = 'loading')
{
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
}
else
{
    ready()
}

function ready()
{
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')

    for(var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++)
    {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }
    
    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-amt')

    for(var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++)
    {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }
    
    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')

    for(var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++)
    {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }
}

function removeCartItem(event)
{
            var buttonClicked = event.target
            buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged()
{
    var input = event.target
    if(isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0)
    {
        input.value = 1
    }
    if(((input.value * 10) % 10) != 0)
    {
        input.value = Math.floor(input.value)
    }
    parseInt(input.value)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event)
{
    var button = event.target
    var price = document.getElementsByClassName('item-price')[0].innerText
    var title = document.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText
    
    addItemToCart(title, price)
}

function addItemToCart(title, price)
{
    window.open('cart.html')
}

function updateCartTotal()
{
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++)
    {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-amt')[0]
        
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('£',''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        var finalPrice = Math.round(((quantity * price) + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
        total = total + finalPrice
    }
    
    var cartTotalContainer1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-container-1')[0]
    var cartTotalContainer2 = cartTotalContainer1.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-container-2')[0]
    cartTotalContainer2.getElementsByClassName('cart-total')[0].innerText = '£' + total
}
```

I have no idea what to do to change data from one file to another. Can anyone help? Also, I would like to only use JS and HTML.

Comment: You cannot edit another file on a server without using a server to do so. If these are static files, you have to set up a PHP or Node.JS server in order to serve different pages, or use AJAX with a server.

Comment: you could use localstorage to store cart items, and display them in cart

Comment: The question is far too broad as you are essentially asking how to build an entire CMS (Content Management System) that involves an editor, uploader, authentication, etc.  It would probably be quicker and far less work to use an e-commerce site like [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/) or [similar](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/software/best-ecommerce-hosting/).